# How to use Python SSHTunnle to forward multiple ports

Tags: python, ssh-tunnel

I need to forward to multiple ports which are sits behind a server

```
server1(22) -> Server2(mysql, 3360) = local 3360
            -> Server3(http, 8080)  = local 8080
            -> Server4(oracle,1234) = local 1234
```

I can only access Server2,3, and 4 via server1.

I am using Python ssltunnel package https://pypi.org/project/sshtunnel/

In example1&2, I can only specify one remote&local bind address.
Not sure how to connect multiple servers(2,3,4)

Example1

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder

server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    'pahaz.urfuclub.ru',
    ssh_username="pahaz",
    ssh_password="secret",
    remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 8080)
)

server.start()

print(server.local_bind_port)  # show assigned local port
# work with `SECRET SERVICE` through `server.local_bind_port`.

server.stop()
```

Example 2

```
import paramiko
import sshtunnel

with sshtunnel.open_tunnel(
    (REMOTE_SERVER_IP, 443),
    ssh_username="",
    ssh_pkey="/var/ssh/rsa_key",
    ssh_private_key_password="secret",
    remote_bind_address=(PRIVATE_SERVER_IP, 22),
    local_bind_address=('0.0.0.0', 10022)
) as tunnel:
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect('127.0.0.1', 10022)
    # do some operations with client session
    client.close()

print('FINISH!')
```

I could use any other Python package that can do the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both examples can be modified slightly to work the way you want.

There is the singular versions of bindings (`local_bind_address` & `remote_bind_address`) and the plural versions of bindings (`local_bind_addresses` & `remote_bind_addresses`.

The singular verisons expects a `tuple` containing variables for the connections, while the plural versions expects a `list` of one or more `tuple(s)`.

Here is a modified version of your example 2:

```
import paramiko
import sshtunnel

tunnels = [("172.16.0.1", 80),
           ("172.16.0.2", 22)]

localPorts = [("127.0.0.1", 1180),
              ("127.0.0.1", 10022)]

with sshtunnel.open_tunnel(
    (REMOTE_SERVER_IP, 22),
    ssh_username="",
    ssh_pkey="/var/ssh/rsa_key",
    ssh_private_key_password="secret",
    remote_bind_addresses=tunnels,
    local_bind_addresses=localPorts
) as tunnel:
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    client.connect('127.0.0.1', 10022)
    # do some operations with client session
    client.close()
```

If the lengths of the lists are the same length, then the IP-addresses / ports will correspond with each other.

In my example above, the following is happening:

> Connection: 172.16.0.1 Port: 80, Is tunneled via: 127.0.0.1 Port: 1180
>
> Connection: 172.16.0.2 Port: 22, Is tunneled via: 127.0.0.1 Port:
>   10022

Answer (score 1):

I am adding this solution for multiple hops on multiple ports:

I have this setup:
[image]
the goal is to access the database by calling my machine on port 33306. This isn't possible because only gateway2 is allowed to speak to the database. We cant access gateway2 because only gateway1 is allowed to speak to it.

the following is the corresponding ssh .config file:

```
Host gateway1
    HostName gtw1_IP_address
    User gtw1_user
    IdentityFile "path_to_gtw1_ssh_key"
    IdentitiesOnly True

Host gateway2
    User gtw2_user
    Hostname gtw2_IP_address
    IdentityFile "path_to_gtw2_ssh_key"
    IdentitiesOnly True
    # mysql
    LocalForward 127.0.0.1:33306 127.0.0.1:3306
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p switch-cede
```

this is how I reproduce it in python:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import config
import pandas as pd
import sshtunnel
from paramiko import SSHClient

with sshtunnel.open_tunnel(
    ssh_username='gtw1_user',
    ssh_address_or_host=('gtw1_IP_address', 22),
    remote_bind_addresses=[('gtw2_IP_address', 22), ('gtw2_IP_address', 33306)],
    local_bind_addresses=[('0.0.0.0', 22), ('0.0.0.0', 33306)], #this line is optional
    ssh_pkey=path_to_gtw1_ssh_key,
) as tunnel1: # tunnel1 is the tunnel between myMachine and gateway1 I believe
    
    print(tunnel1.local_bind_ports)
    with sshtunnel.open_tunnel(
        ssh_address_or_host=('localhost', tunnel1.local_bind_ports[0]),
        remote_bind_addresses=[('127.0.0.1', 22),('127.0.0.1', 3306)],
        local_bind_addresses=[('0.0.0.0', 22), ('127.0.0.1', 33306)],
        ssh_username='gtw2_user',
        ssh_pkey=path_to_gtw2_ssh_key,
    ) as tunnel2: # tunnel2 is the tunnel between gtw1 and gtw2 I believe
       
        print(tunnel2.local_bind_ports)
        db = create_engine(
            f"mysql+pymysql://{config.USER}:{config.PASSWORD}@{config.HOST}:{config.PORT}/{config.DATABASE}")
        print(db)
        query = "SELECT * FROM randomTable LIMIT 10;"
        df = pd.read_sql(query, db)
        print(df)
# note that config is a file holding the credentials to connect to the database
```

Comment: While this is a good answer for your specific problem, I don't think this is a good fit because the problem it solves is only tangentially relevant to the question. I would argue that it would be better if this scenario was posted as a separate question, and answered immediately by yourself.